# PHP code is not executed in Apache, rather the code itself is displayed

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I am new to PHP. Why Apache only displays file content but doesn't execute `index.php`?

I installed prosper202 on apache2 subdomain on ubuntu 14 with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli) (built: Oct 3 2016 13:00:37) and php-fpm, but it only displays the content of `index.php`, it doesn't lead me to setup process.

What's wrong and how to run `index.php`?

Comment: Can you check if everyhting is configured correctly? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11595872/4921289

Comment: Did you restart apache after installing PHP? `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thanks @Marc Scheib, I saw the page is loading, but still have configuration problems(see bellow of my answer)

Answer (score 0):

It's php problem, I reinstalled it and enabled it, now the prosper202 displays PHP write permissions (required for 1-Click Upgrade), it's is not writable.

I checked the installed dir, it has the following:
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jul 14  2015 offers202

Why it complains about write permission?

Thanks!