# cannot enable php8.2 with Apache2 compiled from sources

Tags: php, apache, openssl

I have compiled Apache2 2.4.57 with a custom OpenSSL version, then installed php8.2. It is a test web server I used locally on localhost:8080. The server works with the test page of Apache.

Apache2 is installed under /usr/local/apache2

I used sudo a2enmod php8.2 to enable PHP.

I created a test.php page and copied it under htdocs:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

to test the PHP install but it doesn't work. When I type localhost:8080/test.php in Chrome it only shows the page's code.

I'm not a web dev at all. I followed the following tutorial https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-8-2-on-ubuntu/

Is there anything else to do in the **httpd.conf** to enable PHP?
Is it normal that after running **sudo a2enmod php8.2** I see no modification in **httpd.conf**?

I have also tried to use php8.2-fpm but it doesn't work either.
I'm just planning to stream a simple video to a video player (ffplay) using https with my custom version of OpenSSL.

I thought that Apache+php was simple to install but it seems impossible to configure :-(

Anyone could help?
Thanks

Comment: PHP is simple to install and configure _when installed via package_, because the 95% of the heavy lifting is done by the packager/package manager. When you build from source you take on 100% of that responsibility yourself. Also, a2enmod only creates symlinks between `mods-available` and `mods-enabled`, assumes that the relevant `include` statement is already somewhere in your config, and is technically from the Ubuntu packagers, not Apache itself.

Comment: I just realized that Ubuntu already has an apache2 installed, so when I tried to use the a2enmod it configured php for the pre-installed apache2, not for the one I compiled.
So my question is: WHERE CAN I FIND THE DOCUMENTATION TO ENABLE PHP FOR THE APACHE2 THAT I COMPILED????

Comment: What distribution and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`a2enmod` is a command tools by Debian / Ubuntu written specifically to support their `apache2` package. It is NOT a tool to support custom compiled Apache2. To use PHP with it, you need to manually compile PHP from source code against your compiled copy of Apache2.

This is not recommended because you'd have to manually patch and update your Apache to avoid vulnerability of old version being exploit.

If you do not have a preference to PHP version, you should try to install PHP in one of 2 ways:

1. Apache with mod_php; or
2. Apache with mod_fastcgi + php-fpm

The first method should be more straight forward:

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

If you need PHP 8.2 on your Ubuntu server but still want to use stock Apache package, then you should install  PHP 8.2 with PPA:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install php8.2 libapache2-mod-php8.2 php8.2-mysql
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

P.S. PHP-FPM is very flexible if you need to run multiple PHP versions in parallel. But that would take you a lot more understanding in what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yeung

I followed your advice and managed to compile php8.2 with my Apache version.

I followed the following information: https://gist.github.com/z2z/3bf4c60b7f0c0171d410d54bad088e6e

However, I found out that there were a couple of differences once PHP was compiled. For my purpose, I didn't need any DB so I removed the DB dependencies.

My apache is installed there: **/usr/local/apache2/**
I have a customed version of **openssl** there: **/usr/local/bin/openssl**

Apache compilation is configured in the following way:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/bin/openssl --with-expat=/usr/local/include --enable-so --enable-mime-magic
```

php8.5 compilation is configured in the following way:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --prefix=/usr/local/apache2/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache2/php --disable-cgi --with-zlib --with-gettext --without-pdo-sqlite --without-sqlite3
```

Both compiled and installed with:

```
make
sudo make install
```

The installation requires running (I don't know why...):

```
/usr/local/apache2/build/libtool --finish /home/youruser/Desktop/apache/php-8.2.5/libs
```

Once compiled php8.2 creates the module: php_module for apache2. It can be verified using:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -M
```

It also creates the library **libphp.so** under modules.

To activate php I added the following to **httdp.conf**

```
LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so

<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(?:ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(?:ar|p|ps|tml)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
# 
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Then I created a php file in **htdocs** with:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

to verify that PHP works!

Fortunately, all this would only be required if you need to use PHP with a custom compilation of Apache2!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [PHP not interpreted, showing in view source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49315411/1086907)

For php 8.2

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.2
sudo a2enmod php8.2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```